# React took so long to deploy in google cloud

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I have a React app on GCP that took at least 18 minutes for deploying, and sometimes it goes up to 25 minutes. Is this normal? how can I decrease this time

Comment: Hey @SaiChandraGadde . Thanks for your reply, honestly I asked my colleagues about this and they told me that it took almost same amount of time for their projects, so I thought it might be it and for now, I just let that go.  but I will check all those steps that u told me as soon as I get some free time. thanks again 3>

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to several reasons such as

1. Image building
2. Your internet connection
3. Image size
4. Cache

Also check the logs for any warnings or errors to further debug the issue.

You can reduce deployment time by using the [deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices#managing_the_size_of_your_deployments).

You can also raise a [support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if required.